# Verb orders in english speaking

Tags: questions

When I speak that:

> "I will go home and do some work and take rest then go to market"

it means I will do work after reaching home then take rest then go to market.

So could we speak such sentence like this?

Comment: You will not hear an English speaker say _"I will go home and do some work and take rest then go to market"._ The sentence does express what you mean to express, but there should be a conjunction and a comma before the last clause, thus: _"I will go home and do some work and take rest, **and** then go to market"._ That makes it grammatical, but it's still not a sentence we would speak.

Comment: We would say "take a rest" (**rest** as noun) or simply "rest" (**rest** as verb).

Answer (score 2):

To follow on to what @P.E.Dant says (in his comment that should've perhaps been an answer), it seems like too many actions are being strung together for a single sentence. More likely, we’d split it into two sentences:

> *I will go home, do some work, and then take a rest. After that, I’ll go to the market.*

As a footnote, in the U.S., we’re more likely to say “to *the* market” than “to market.”